# python tesseract OCR taking 13~ seconds to read a 1000x14000 website screenshot, is there a way to speed this up?

Tags: python, performance, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

so basically the whole question is in the title: I have an extremely simple pytesseract script running on a screenshot of a website with a bit non-standard dimensions of 1000x14000 px. The issue is that the following script is taking approximately 13 seconds to run. In all of the examples on yt I've seen, the tesseract scripts are basically instantaneous.

My question is - is the long execution time caused by the dimension? Or is there a known issue that can be causing this to happen? I have tesseract 5.0.1 installed, and run python 3.10. I have 16 gb of ram and a 4 core 3.5 ghz CPU (i5-6600K), so I don't think this can be the bottleneck. Is there a way to speed this up? I guess I don't particularily need to use python, can switching to c++ help here? But even still, I don't think this should be taking 13 seconds, what can be wrong here?

```
import time
import cv2
import pytesseract
start_time = time.time()
img = cv2.imread('myimage.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Since you have an image on disk, you should be able to just do `print(pytesseract.image_to_string('myimage.png'))` instead of loading the image using OpenCV.

Comment: @AKX it seems that it does help by about 2 seconds, thanks. So 11 seconds left 8)

Comment: "1000x14000 px" is pretty huge for an image recognition task. Can't you resize the image to drastically reduce the amount of work (eg. 250x3500)? Can you share an example of recognized image?

Comment: @JérômeRichard sure, what I need are the "name", "buy" and "sell" columns from this example image: https://ibb.co/R76SBJ2

Comment: Ok. You can detect the shopping cart icon on the left on each line so to extract each line of the web page. Then you can give it to pytesseract. This should be faster end result in a better output. Moreover, lines can certainly be computed in parallel. The current result on the whole image is probably useless (I guess it is nearly impossible to parse correctly). You could even split each lines to blocks so to extract each columns separately. This is probably not easy to do though.